# Use System.Web.Hosting to host pages inside an ASP.Net application

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, hosting

I would like to know if it is possible to host pages inside of a directory in a currently running web application.  I would like this functionality so that I can dynamically add pages/assemblies without recycling the app pool. I think it is possible to do so and I think I am getting close, but I keep getting a server error when I try to load up a page:  The path '/App_GlobalResources/' maps to a directory outside this application, which is not supported.

I am loading all the current assemblies and a couple other ones into a new appDomain and then trying to process a httpWorkerRequest. 
The code I am providing is poor, I know, but I am just trying to get this thing to breathe.

```
Public Class ApplicationHostHelper
    Private _appDomain As AppDomain
    Public Function ConstructNewAppDomain() As AppDomain
        Dim testDirectory As String = "<appDirectory>\TestDomains\TestDomain"

        Dim args As New AppDomainSetup()
        args.ApplicationBase = testDirectory
        args.ConfigurationFile = "Web.Config"


        Dim assemblyName As String
        Dim assemblyNames As New List(Of String)()
        For Each ass As System.Reflection.Assembly In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            assemblyName = String.Empty
            If Not ass.GetType().Namespace.Equals("System.Reflection.Emit", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then assemblyName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ass.Location)
            If Not IsSystemDependencyName(assemblyName) AndAlso Not assemblyName = String.Empty Then
                If Not System.IO.File.Exists(testDirectory & "\" & assemblyName) Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(ass.Location, testDirectory.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\" & assemblyName, True)
                    If Not assemblyNames.Contains(assemblyName) Then assemblyNames.Add(assemblyName)
                End If

            End If
        Next
        Dim splitPath() As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "").Split("/"c)
        Dim basePath As String = Nothing
        For x As Int32 = 0 To splitPath.Length - 3
            basePath += splitPath(x) & "\"
        Next
        basePath &= "Web.config"
        Dim newWebConfigPath As String = testDirectory.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\" & "Web.config"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(basePath) AndAlso Not System.IO.File.Exists(newWebConfigPath) Then System.IO.File.Copy(basePath, newWebConfigPath)

        Dim retval As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("CustomPagesDomain", Nothing, args)
        retval.SetData(".appId", "CustomPagesDomain")
        retval.SetData(".appDomain", "*")
        retval.SetData(".appPath", testDirectory)
        retval.SetData(".appVPath", "/")
        retval.SetData(".domainId", "CustomPagesDomain")
        retval.SetData(".hostingVirtualPath", "/")
        retval.SetData(".hostingInstallDir", testDirectory)
        _appDomain = retval
        Return retval
    End Function

    Public Function LoadPage(ByVal textWriter As System.IO.TextWriter) As AppDomain
        Dim myHost As CustomPagesHost = CType(CreateApplicationHost(), CustomPagesHost)
        myHost.ProcessRequest("StatsReport.aspx", textWriter)
        Return _appDomain
    End Function

    Public Function CreateApplicationHost() As Object
        Dim tempAppDomain As AppDomain = ConstructNewAppDomain()
        Dim oh As System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle = tempAppDomain.CreateInstance(GetType(CustomPagesHost).Module.Assembly.FullName, GetType(CustomPagesHost).FullName)
        Return oh.Unwrap()
    End Function


    Public Shared Function IsSystemDependencyName(ByVal potentialSystemAssemblyName As String) As Boolean
        If potentialSystemAssemblyName.ToLower = "system" Then Return True
        If potentialSystemAssemblyName.ToLower = "mscorlib" Then Return True
        If potentialSystemAssemblyName.Split("."c)(0).ToLower = "system" Then Return True
        If potentialSystemAssemblyName.Split("."c)(0).ToLower = "microsoft" Then Return True
        Return False
    End Function

End Class

Public Class CustomPagesHost
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject
    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal page As String, ByVal textWriter As System.IO.TextWriter)

        Dim hwr As HttpWorkerRequest = New System.Web.Hosting.SimpleWorkerRequest(page, Nothing, textWriter)
        HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(hwr)
    End Sub
End Class


Private Sub _loadAppDomain_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _loadAppDomain.Click
Dim cHelper As New ApplicationHostHelper()
        Dim testDomain As AppDomain = Nothing
        Dim textWriter As System.IO.TextWriter
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        textWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(ms)
        Try

            testDomain = cHelper.LoadPage(textWriter)
            textWriter.Flush()
            ms.Position = 0
            _status.Text = New System.IO.StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd()

        Catch ex As Exception
            _status.Text = ex.ToString()
        Finally
            If Not testDomain Is Nothing Then
                AppDomain.Unload(testDomain)
                DumpFiles("<appDirectory>\TestDomains\TestDomain\")
            End If

        End Try
End Sub
```

I would really appreciate any help on this topic. I can't seem to make progress anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you're trying to fix/avoid?  Why don't you want to recycle the app pool?

Comment: I'm with Ek0nomik: There's really not much of a reason to avoid an app pool recycle.  This seems like you are making things a lot more complicated than they need to be

Comment: @Justin, what you are trying to do is a lot trickier - ASP.NET hosting code is much involved and unless there is clear public API (which I am not aware), you may not want to go this route. How exactly app pool recycle affects you? For example, if you want to avoid it due to loss of in-process session state then you can consider shifting it to out of process etc.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons:
1. If a custom page is loaded and has faulty coding, I want it to be in it's own app domain so it doesn't take out the main site.
2. We use in-proc session, which sucks, but taking it out of process is really not an option at this time unfortunately.

I know this problem is tricky, but I really think it is possible. I dont care all that much if the solution is complex, it is what I think will work best.  Thanks for the responses so far.